# Mapping the Left Alt key to Control and Alt Gr to just Alt

Tags: windows, emacs, keymap

On my laptop, I use Emacs. However, I don't have a left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and I considered mapping the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) to just <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Meta). This way, I can just hit the keys with my thumbs. How would I do this?

I'm using Windows right now, but I also might want to try this on Linux later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remap virtually any key to any other key using AutoHotkey. Check out the remap site: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm

The code should have worked:

```
LAlt::LCtrl
LControl & RAlt::Alt
```

For a complete List of keys look here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

---

EDIT:

since this solution does not work (for whatever reason), I suggest looking at this answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229633/how-to-globally-map-altgr-key-to-alt-key

This guy had the same problem and managed to remap Alt Gr to Alt in the registry (which is more reliable anyway).

Comment: I get: "Error at line 2. Line Text: Alt. Error: This line does not contain a recognized action."

Comment: darn, this shoulda worked. Sorry. I get the same error. Corrected the answer with new info.

Answer (score 3):

On linux you can use `xev` and `xmodmap`.

Start `xev` from a terminal and look at its output to figure out
what's the keycode of your to key.

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1400001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 2274037, (436,185), root:(437,636),
    state 0x0, keycod*emphasized text*e 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Here the keycode of my `Alt_L` key is 64.
Now use `xmodmap` to assign a new keysym to this keycode.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Control_L"
```